# Typing [tag:.] freezes live answer/question preview

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

Just try typing `[tag:.]` and see for yourself.

Comment: hmmm.. No repro here

Comment: @Tijesunimi - type that as an answer. Keep typing stuff after it - do you see it in the preview?

Comment: `Recursive call to converter.makeHtml`

Comment: @Oded OKay. I thought he meant whenever you type it, even after an answer, the entire preview is distorted